# Webpack chunking. No content appearing - chunks not loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, chunks, chunking

It's been a day I'm trying to solve this annoying but, I'm sure, simple issue.
I am trying to divide my **bundle.js** into chunks to optimize website loading time.

Here is  my **webpack.config** file :

```
module.exports = {
devServer: {
historyApiFallback: true
},
entry: {
index: ["./src/index.js"],
vendor: [
  "react",
  "react-dom",
  "react-redux",
  "react-router",
  "react-router-dom",
  "redux"
]
},
output: {
path: __dirname + '/public/views',
filename: "[name].js",
publicPath: "/views/"
},
module: {
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: "babel-loader",
    exclude: [/node_modules/, /pdfmake.js$/]
  },
  {
    test: /\.json$/,
    loader: "json-loader"
  }
]
},
plugins: [
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: "vendor",
  filename: "vendor.js",
  minChunks: Infinity
}),
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: "meta",
  chunks: ["vendor"],
  filename: "meta.js"
}),
new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  title: "Deals",
  filename:  __dirname + "/views/index.ejs",
  template: __dirname + "/views/template.ejs",
  inject: false
}),
new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
  rel: "preload",
  as: "script",
  include: "all"
}),
new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
]
};
```

Here is my my simplified **index.ejs**, file created by running webpack code, result from template.ejs :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <link href="/pace.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://verygoodprof.fr/" />
    <link rel="preload" as="script" href="/views/index.js">
    <link rel="preload" as="script" href="/views/vendor.js">
    <link rel="preload" as="script" href="/views/meta.js">
</head>

<body>

    <noscript>
        <a href="http://enable-javascript.com/">Javascript must me enabled to use this site.</a>
    </noscript>

    <div class="text-center root" id="root">

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here, I see I've got my preloaded chunks, dynamically written, as wanted, and those chunks are in the correct folder, created after running the webpack code.

And here is my **index.js** file (React), stated to be the index entry in webpack.config file

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <AppInit>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
          <ProfRegisteringModal />
          <Switch>
            {/* <Route path="/inscription/:user" component={Registering} />
            <Route path="/inscription" component={Registering} />
            <Route path="/connexion" component={SigningIn} />
            <Route path="/equipe" component={TeamPres} />
            <Route path="/" component={AppContainer} /> */}
            <Route
              path="/inscription/:user"
              getComponent={(location, callback) => {
                require.ensure(
                  [],
                  function(require) {
                    callback(
                      null,
                      require("./components/registering/registering_landing_page.js")
                    );
                  },
                  "registerChunk"
                );
              }}
            />
            <Route
              path="/inscription"
              getComponent={(location, callback) => {
                require.ensure(
                  [],
                  function(require) {
                    callback(
                      null,
                      require("./components/registering/registering_landing_page.js")
                    );
                  },
                  "registerChunk"
                );
              }}
            />
            <Route
              path="/connexion"
              getComponent={(location, callback) => {
                require.ensure(
                  [],
                  function(require) {
                    callback(
                      null,
                      require("./containers/registering/signing_in.js")
                    );
                  },
                  "signinChunk"
                );
              }}
            />
            <Route
              path="/equipe"
              getComponent={(location, callback) => {
                require.ensure(
                  [],
                  function(require) {
                    callback(null, require("./components/team_pres.js"));
                  },
                  "teampresChunk"
                );
              }}
            />
            <Route
              path="/"
              getComponent={(location, callback) => {
                require.ensure(
                  [],
                  function(require) {
                    callback(null, require("./containers/app_container.js"));
                  },
                  "appContainerChunk"
                );
              }}
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AppInit>
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector(".root")
);
```

The first thing I notice is that the chunks that are supposed to be build are correctly built for **vendor** and **meta** but not for my inner react components. But this is not the major issue, the fact is, when running the server locally, **I can't see my react app at all**. The index.ejs file is correctly loaded though when I check in the console.

**Everything was working perfectly when using a simple bundle.js file with everything inside (no chunks)**. With an index.ejs pointing to it as

```
<script src="/views/bundle.js"></script>
```

### Thank you very much for your help !

## EDIT

This **webpack.config** file made it work (credits to @margaretkru):

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  entry: {
    app:"./src/index.js",
    vendor: [
      "axios",
      "jquery",
      "react",
      "react-dom",
      "react-redux",
      "react-router",
      "react-router-dom",
      "redux"
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/views',
    filename: "[name].js",
    publicPath: "/views/"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /pdfmake.js$/]
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: "json-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename:  __dirname + "/views/index.ejs",
      template: __dirname + "/views/template.ejs",
      inject: 'body',
      chunks: ['vendor', 'app'],
      chunksSortMode: 'manual'
    }),
    new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
      rel: "preload",
      include: ["vendor", "app"]
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
  ]
};new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: "vendor",
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename:  __dirname + "/views/index.ejs",
      template: __dirname + "/views/template.ejs",
      inject: 'body',
      chunks: ['vendor', 'app'],
      chunksSortMode: 'manual'
    }),
    new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
      rel: "preload",
      include: ["vendor", "app"]
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
  ]
};
```

The real issue was not the loaded scripts ordering but more that I was not actually loading the scripts after "pre-loading" them : The "inject" line of the HTMLWebpackPlugin helped since it injected those two lines :

```
<script src="/views/vendor.js"/> 
<script src="/views/app.js"/>
```

in my index.ejs body

Comment: so I see that the order of scripts that are loaded in `index.ejs` is incorrect, first should be loaded `vendor.js` and `meta.js` and only THEN `index.js`. But I don't understand why the order is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of the scripts that are loaded in index.ejs is incorrect. Now it is:

```
<link rel="preload" as="script" href="/views/index.js">
<link rel="preload" as="script" href="/views/vendor.js">
```

This means your `index.js` will be loaded before `vendor.js` causing your app to not appear at all. First all your app's dependencies should be loaded (`vendor.js`) and only then `index.js` since you need the dependencies to be present while executing your custom code. So it should be:

```
<link rel="preload" as="script" href="/views/vendor.js">
<link rel="preload" as="script" href="/views/index.js">
```

---

Edit:

As we figured out eventually, the issue was not in the order of the scripts, but due to the fact that the scripts weren't actually loaded in the `html`. For that they need to be added as chunks in `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and injected into `index.html`:

```
 new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "Deals",
      filename:  __dirname + "/views/index.ejs",
      template: __dirname + "/views/template.ejs",
      inject: 'body',
      chunks: ['vendor', 'index']
    })
```

Moreover, the configuration for the chunk `meta` was removed completely. All the rest of the configuration (including `PreloadWebpackPlugin`) was fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The suggestion you made do not work though. The order is still not correct and, even if I change the order manually in index.ejs, the website is not loaded

Comment: do you see any errors in the console? could you post them if you do?

Comment: You're right, I could delete it ? I thought It was something to "bundle up" the other chunks?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean :) I would go with [this](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#explicit-vendor-chunk) configuration, the simplest one, and test whether it works. If it doesnt try removing `PreloadWebpackPlugin` completely and see if something changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163252/discussion-between-louis-and-margaretkru).

Comment: Btw, the real issue was not the loaded scripts ordering but more that I was not actually loading the scripts after "pre-loading" them : The "inject" line of the HTMLWebpackPlugin helped since it injected those two lines : <script src="/views/vendor.js"/> <script src="/views/app.js"/> in my index.ejs body

Comment: Perfect! I updated the answer so that it can help others in case they encounter the same problem :)